# Custom ListView : related to paticular item

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have created a custom list view in which two text view and one image view (showing the list item is favorite or not) is used. Image view will appear if someone selects that item as a favorite otherwise it will not display.  An SQLite DB is used for storing favorite list item. And using this DB a list view is populated. All is working fine but when I mark the list item as a favorite sudden on that item list image view will not appear but that  SQLite DB is updated with this new item list so that when I reload the same page it is appearing as favorite item.How can I fix this?

Comment: Without providing what have you tried/code, do you think you would get suggestions/solutions?

Comment: ok ... i am posting my code.

Comment: I am not able to post my code each time it says please write some context to explain code.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to provide some example code, but you could re-draw the listview item its self with the onclick invalidating the item's view or probably the easier way by notifying the adapter of a change.

e.g.

```
@Override 
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstance )
{
    ...
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter( this );
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.list_view );
    listView.setAdapter( myAdapter );

    listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> adapter, View listItemView, 
            int position, long id )
        {
           ...
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't a perfect solution, but gives you an idea.

Comment: Last time I have only getter function in class so  that I created getter and setter class which is used  to store two string field. And one boolean variable which is used to find the favorite or not favorite. By finding that list item i am able to update it because I just need to change the boolean variable.After updating an arraylist , I called notifyDataSetChanged(); due to which list is again reflected without reloading the activity. I hope this will be helpful enough.